# Capybara not able to recognize ajax loaded elements.?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, capybara

In my **Rails 3** application, I have a "**image**" on my HTML page, which creates a "**div**" element in html page, when **clicked**.

I have to test the creation of this new "**div**" through **RSpec** (and i am using **Capybara** for views based testing).

I have written the following code :

```
it "clicks the extended details button" do
    Capybara.default_wait_time = 5
    within('.table_expand') do
      find("#img_dealer_code_04039").click
      should have_selector('#extended_details_04039')
    end
end
```

yeah i have already added, `:js=>true` in corresponding `describe`.

I thought the problem would be of Ajax time , so i added `Capybara.default_wait_time = 5` for it to load properly. (But it didnt work)

Also i tried putting `:visible=>true` in line should `have_selector('#extended_details_04039')` , but with no success..

Is there anything that i am missing..??

Please help me...I am stuck with this from quite a long time..!!

Comment: Which capybara driver are you using?

Comment: selenium.. but i have tried with webkit also..!!

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/478

are you sure that you don't have duplicated ID on site? 
Try to save it to file and check the source for duplications.

To see what's going on the page try 
page.save_and_open_page method

Comment: No, i dont have any duplicate ID in html. I'll try the save and open page method though.

Answer (score 0):

Is img part of your ID or is it the tag type? I believe you shoul have

```
find("img#dealer_code_0409").click
```

Comment: I think "click" on the image is working..because there is no error on that line..but since the "div" is dynamically generated, it is not able to identify it.